# Setting Size of String Buffer When Accessing Windows Registry

Tags: vbscript, registry, wmi

I'm working on a VBScript web application that has a newly-introduced requirement to talk to the registry to pull connection string information instead of using hard-coded strings. I'm doing performance profiling because of the overhead this will introduce, and noticed in Process Monitor that reading the value returns two `BUFFER OVERFLOW` results before finally returning a success.

[image: Registry Work]

Looking online, [Mark Russinovich posted about this topic](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/06/04/buffer-overflows-in-regmon-traces.aspx) a few years back, indicating that since the size of the registry entry isn't known, a default buffer of 144 bytes is used. Since there are two buffer overflow responses, the amount of time taken by the entire call is approximately doubled (and yes, I realize the difference is 40 microseconds, but with 1,000 or more page hits per second, I'm willing to invest some time in optimization).

My question is this: is there a way to tell WMI what the size of the registry value is before it tries to get it? Here's a sample of the code I'm using to access the registry:

```
svComputer = "." ' Local machine is simply "."
ivHKey = &H80000002 ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002 (from WinReg.h)
svRegPath = "SOFTWARE\Path\To\My\Values"

Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & svComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
oRegistry.GetStringValue ivHKey, svRegPath, "Value", svValue
```

Comment: According to the article, it affects any reg values > 132 bytes. Can you shorten your connection string or lookup a DSN instead? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, @Bond, there's nothing I can do about the length of the connection string itself. If there's no way to set the buffer size, then I've considered going that route (keeping the most volatile/confidential bits in the registry and concatenating it with the rest)--it's just a much more messy solution than I had wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBScript strings are strings. They are however long they need to be. You don't pre-define their length. Also, if performance is that much of an issue for you, you should consider using a compiled instead of an interpreted language (or a cache for values you read before).

Comment: The problem isn't the VBScript string, but the WMI GetStringValue using a buffer to read the value out of the registry.

Also, I totally agree about changing the platform and caching, but this is the last remnant of a legacy system for which neither are an option.

Comment: VBScript doesn't know anything (nor does it have access to) the inner workings of the `GetStringValue` implementation. So, the answer remains: no can do.